# Update parameter of URL (without refresh)

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, updates

I know this is a very documented subject but after hours and hours of research I'm now stuck.
I'm making a quiz, and when a choice is made I would like to update the corresponding parameter on the URL.

https://deusbot-trading.com/quiz/age=&exp=&asset=

This is my URL, generated with :

```
let refresh = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?age=&exp=&asset=';    
window.history.replaceState({ path: refresh }, '', refresh);
```

And I would like to update some parameters of this url when users click on a button.
For example, I would like to assign a value to "age" without changing the rest of the url :

https://deusbot-trading.com/quiz/age=45+&exp=&asset=

---

I tried :

```
window.history.replaceState({ 'age=', 'age=45+');
```

But this doesn't seems to work.
I hope someone can throw some light on how to dynamicaly modify parameters value of the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using replaceState you should do it like this:
It will produce the expected result

https://deusbot-trading.com/quiz/age=45+&exp=&asset=

after you apply this

```
history.replaceState({}, null, location.href.replace('age=','age=45+'))
```

for further changes just continue with the same way:

```
history.replaceState({}, null, location.href.replace('exp=','exp=1000'))
```

**Notes**

The only part affecting the url is the 3rd argument

`history.replaceState(data, title [, url ])`

Comment: This does work, but on the next question on the quiz, when I do the same with 'exp=' it erase 'age=45&' (every strings before exp=)

Comment: If you need a live example, here's the link of my quiz : https://deusbot-trading.com/quiz/

Comment: @GuillaumeTdlg check my answer again

Comment: Wow thank you very much it is working great ! The only probleme is that when I choose another answer on the exp, it keep adding up to the url, like so:
https://deusbot-trading.com/quiz/?age=45+&exp=5years+3-5years5years+3-5years5years+3-5years5years+3-5years&asset=

Comment: you should post he code logic that is behind the clicking on another answer... also you should ask another question for this I believe

Comment: Alright, Its working well now, thank you very much again Eugen!
Its not very clean, but I fixed this problem with a simple reset of my url parameter.

    history.replaceState({}, null, location.href.replace('exp=none','exp='))

Answer (score 0):

[History API pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API#Example_of_pushState_method)
plus [searchparams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
let refresh = new URL("https://deusbot-trading.com/quiz/?age=45+&exp=&asset=") // new URL(location.href)
const refreshObj = { "path": refresh }
refresh.searchParams.set("age",50)

console.log(refresh)

// window.history.replaceState(refreshObj, '', refresh); // has to be on the same origin
```